# Device Requirements For Progressive Web Apps (PWA)

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, requirements

So my question is pretty straight forward. What are the device requirements for a device to run a progressive web app? I've tried googling but I keep getting results for the minimum requirements for creating a PWA, however that's not what I'm interested in. For instance, say I buy a feature phone(ie a low budget phone) that has a browser with JS support, would that phone be able to run a Progressive Web App?

Comment: it depends on the browser

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this question elsewhere?